# Why doesn't this simple RegEx work?

Tags: php, regex

I feel really stupid for asking, but I don't seem to be able to find out why this simple php script doesn't work and returns False (which is an php error). I am kind of a newbie using regex though.

```
var_dump( preg_match('^[a-zA-Z]+$', 'Welcome') );
```

Comment: Turn error reporting up to full, so you'll see the error message.

Comment: In particular, you would have seen the error message `Warning:  preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'`, which gives you [something to search on](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A++preg_match%28%29%3A+No+ending+delimiter+%27%5E%27).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using regex delimiter as in:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', 'Welcome');
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have no delimiters set in place for your regular expression, in which it would fail and prompt you with an error message. A delimiter can be any *non-alphanumeric*, *non-backslash*, *non-whitespace* character.

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', 'Welcome');
```

Comment: The fact that 4 minutes after the question is asked, it already feels like a "late answer" ought to indicate that the question is a candidate for a close vote. Putting that out there.

Comment: It is true. I feel very guilty for posting such a (it is) stupid question :/

Comment: @Ivotje50: It's okay. But remember to have error reporting enabled. And always Google first (and search on SO as well).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [delimiters](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
var_dump( preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z]+$#', 'Welcome') );
                      ^           ^ here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [pattern delimiters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), for example:

```
var_dump( preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', 'Welcome') );
```